# TNS:received bad datatype in NSWMARKER packet

Tags: jdbc, oracle10g, java-7, jboss6.x

I am using Oracle 10.2.0.5 as database, ojdbc14.jar as jdbc driver and calling this via jdbc from an application deployed in JBoss EAP 6.4. I am sometimes getting the following exception while connecting to database:

```
11:01:53,804 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6) java.lang.Exception: ORA-12155: TNS:received bad datatype in NSWMARKER packet
11:01:53,804 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6) 
11:01:53,804 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at dk.tdc.soa.faslink.intern.commonfunctions.DBAccess.query2(DBAccess.java:115)
11:01:53,804 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at dk.tdc.soa.faslink.intern.functions.FasoDetailRequestFunction.execute(FasoDetailRequestFunction.java:426)
11:01:53,805 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at dk.tdc.soa.faslink.extern.RestEndpoint.fasoDetailRequest(RestEndpoint.java:426)
11:01:53,805 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
11:01:53,805 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
11:01:53,805 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
11:01:53,805 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
11:01:53,806 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:168)
11:01:53,806 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:269)
11:01:53,806 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:227)
11:01:53,806 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:216)
11:01:53,806 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:541)
11:01:53,806 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:523)
11:01:53,807 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:125)
11:01:53,807 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
11:01:53,807 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
11:01:53,807 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
11:01:53,807 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
11:01:53,807 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
11:01:53,807 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
11:01:53,808 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231)
11:01:53,808 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
11:01:53,808 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
11:01:53,808 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150)
11:01:53,808 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
11:01:53,808 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
11:01:53,809 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
11:01:53,809 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854)
11:01:53,809 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
11:01:53,809 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926)
11:01:53,809 ERROR [stderr] (http-/10.150.101.98:8080-6)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can anyone plase suggest why I am getting this intermittent exception?

Comment: ojdbc14 is for Java 1.4, which means the version of the driver is also very old. Please try a more recent version of the Oracle JDBC driver. Likely the version you are currently using doesn't support some parts of the Oracle version you're connecting to.

Comment: But I found that for connecting to oracle 10.2.x, I must use ojdbc14.jar. The next version of ojdbc is ojdbc6.jar which is for Oracle 11g.

Comment: The 11g version of the JDBC drivers supports Oracle 9 (iirc) and 10 as well.